# Extension Option display blank in Edge only in my Extension

Tags: jquery

**I'm developing an extension myself and ran into a problem where options page is blank in Edge. There is problem in accessing the extension data, It give me error of  'SecurityError'. My extension working in all other browser so I could not identify what caused the issue and what was the solution to it.
Can you please guide me through the issue so that I can solve it? 
here is my manifest.json file.**

```js
{
  "author":"Team",
  "background":{
    "page":"background.html",
    "persistent":true
  },
  "browser_action":{
    "default_icon":{
      "19":"img/icon19.png",
      "38":"img/icon38.png"
    },
    "default_popup":"button/popup.html",
    "default_title":"__MSG_click_for_details__"
  },
  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "all_frames":true,
      "js":[
        "js/bandaids.js"
      ],
      "matches":[
        "*://*.facebook.com/*",
        "*://*.mail.live.com/*",
        "*://*.mastertoons.com/*",
        "*://*.mobilmania.cz/*",
        "*://*.zive.cz/*",
        "*://*.doupe.cz/*",
        "*://*.e15.cz/*",
        "*://*.sportrevue.cz/*",
        "*://*.autorevue.cz/*",
        "*://*.youtube.com/*"
      ],
      "run_at":"document_start"
    },
    {
      "all_frames":true,
      "js":[
        "lib/jquery.min.js",
        "lib/punycode.min.js",
        "js/port.js",
        "js/functions.js",
        "filtering/filteroptions.js",
        "js/adblock_start_common.js",
        "js/adblock_start_chrome.js",
        "contentscript.js"
      ],
      "matches":[
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "run_at":"document_start"
    },
    {
      "all_frames":false,
      "js":[
        "uiscripts/blacklisting/rightclick_hook.js"
      ],
      "matches":[
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "run_at":"document_end"
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy":"default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *; img-src *;",

  "default_locale":"en",
  "description":"Hassle-free ad blocker with a twist. Win cash prizes by opting into acceptable ads, one raffle ticket for every ad you see.",
  "icons":{
    "128":"img/icon128.png",
    "16":"img/icon16.png",
    "48":"img/icon48.png"
  },
  "incognito":"spanning",
  "key":"emghbjjpdkocbmeibmkblchiognbjiji",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "minimum_chrome_version":"49",
  "name":"",
  "short_name": "",
  "optional_permissions":[
    "management"
  ],
  "options_page":"options/index.html",
  "permissions":[
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "privacy",
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "idle",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "webNavigation",
    "alarms",
    "storage",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "version":"0.0.6",
  "web_accessible_resources":[
    "jquery/css/images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png",
    "jquery/css/images/ui-icons_056b93_256x240.png",
    "jquery/css/images/ui-icons_d8e7f3_256x240.png",
    "jquery/css/jquery-ui.custom.css",
    "jquery/css/override-page.css",
    "img/icon19.png",
    "img/icon24.png"
  ]
}
```